# Is there a JQuery plugin for this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, templates, yui

I am currently using YUI datatable, but it is buggy: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/

Is there another similar plugin that can do this , in JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery [Flexigrid](http://www.flexigrid.info/).

See also [jQuery Grid Recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations).

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed this!

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [jqGrid](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqGrids) for this.  I haven't used YUI that much for this, but based on demo comparison, seems to be the best match around.

Answer (score 0):

I've been a big fan of tablesorter:

http://tablesorter.com/docs/

It's pretty simple, but easy to extend.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: [TableSorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/). Much better than YUI (and easier to use).